# Google Scripts fill array of values and their locations from cells

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I'm using Google Scripts to manipulate the values in a spreadsheet. Here's what I've got:

```
var Habits = sheet.getRange("C5:D100");

var HABITS = [Habits.getCell(1, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(2, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(3, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(4, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(5, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(6, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(7, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(8, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(9, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(10, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(11, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(12, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(13, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(14, 2).getValue(),
          Habits.getCell(15, 2).getValue(),
          ];
```

So you can probably see what I'm trying to do. Trying to get all the values in a series of cells as an array. But the range of values might fluctuate and I don't want to have to make changes to the script. Here's one solution that I've tried but I can't get to work (But it leaves HABITS undefined):

```
var Habits = sheet.getRange("C5:D100");
var HABITS

for (var i = 0; i < Habits.getHeight; i++){

  if (Habits[i].getCell(i,1).isBlank()){
    break;
  }
  else{
    HABITS[i] = Habits.getCell(i,2).getValue();
  }
}
```

The second problem is, as I get these values, I need to write new values back in their place, so somehow I need to record the location of each in a similar array.

Here's something I tried to change the values (this will replace a "checked habit" and make it "unchecked" aka- replace an X in a spreadsheet with nothing), but it doesn't work with HABITS being undefined and therefore of no length:

```
for (var i = 0; i < HABITS.length; i++) {
  if (HABITS[i] == "X"){
    Favorloc.setValue(Favorloc.getValue() + 1);
    Habits[i].setValue();
  }
}
```

Any suggestions? (Also, if you need to see my full script or spreadsheet to get a better idea of what I'm doing, let me know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

always worth having a dig around [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange%28%29) :)

```
var range = sheet.getDataRange(); // REFERENCE THE ENTIRE AREA CONTAINING DATA ON THIS SHEET
var values = range.getValues(); // RETURN THE DATA FROM THE RANGE INTO AN ARRAY
```

then you can do the same in reverse, making sure your array and the area that you want to assign it to are exactly the same shape - I use [the 'offset' method of the Range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) to do that.